cant put substraction character as string
I am trying to write a bash script to create a filename using some variables, I should add "-" character in some places to obtain the correct filepath. However when I use the following command, it turns me an empty space instead of - character:
FILEDIR=${root_path}${year}/${month}/${day}/${filename_zero}"_"${year}"-"${month}"-"${day}"-"${filename_one} 

public/2024/03/18/105610_2024 03 18 12:33:42.mp4

The result that I need:
public/2024/03/18/105610_2024-03-18-12:33:42.mp4

I have tried many other things like single quote, non-quote, but it doesnt work...

Exactly how do you print the FILEDIR? What is the value of IFS in your script?

Sorry, that's impossible. A variable assignment does not produce any output. Explain how you go from FILEDIR=... to obtaining public/2024...

Please post a [mre].

Make sure you quote all your variables. OTOH, there's no need to quote the _ and - between the variables.

Unable to reproduce: https://ideone.com/R9ubBK

You are using the quotes incorrectly. Instead of surrounding each individual symbol with quotes, surround the entire value in quotes.
#!/bin/bash

root_path="example"
year="2024"
month="May"
day="9"
filename_zero="filename_0"
filename_one="filename_1"

FILEDIR="${root_path}${year}/${month}/${day}/${filename_zero}_${year}-${month}-${day}-${filename_one}"

echo "${FILEDIR}"

Which prints the following
example2024/May/9/filename_0_2024-May-9-filename_1


Thank you for the quick answer it works!
My fault was not to use single quotes when defining FILEDIR= variable and I was doing echo $FILEDIR instead of echo  "${FILEDIR}"

Note that for variables declaration, the quotes aren't needed: FILEDIR="..." is the same as FILEDIR=.... On the other hand, it is needed when reading the variable (like using echo) if you don't want it to be split based on $IFS.
